# How to prove that an action-value function optimal for one problem formulation is also optimal for another?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, decision-theory

I want to ask about the intuition/where-to-look/what-to-try if I want to prove that an action value function optimal for a problem is also optimal for another reformulation of that smae problem. For example, a common approach to solve DEC-POMDP is to recast the problem into a common-knowledge-MDP. In this case (and in any similar case) What is the approach to follow in order to prove that the optimal action-value function optimal for the single agent reformulation is also optimal for the multi-agent formulation?

Answer (score 0):

The reduction of a Dec-POMDP to a centralized MDP that you mention is discussed at length in the technical report ["Dec-POMDPs as Non-Observable MDPs"](https://www.fransoliehoek.net/docs/Oliehoek14IASTR.pdf) by Oliehoek and Amato.

Further background that can help understand the method can be found in ["Sufficient plan-time statistics for decentralized POMDPs"](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/13/Papers/053.pdf) in IJCAI'13 also by Oliehoek.
A related approach dealing with common/individual knowledge and information gathering is ["Multi-agent active perception with prediction rewards"](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/hash/9db6faeef387dc789777227a8bed4d52-Abstract.html) in NeurIPS'20 by Lauri and Oliehoek. (Disclaimer: I am one of the authors).